# How to calculate Session Duration or Call Duration for a session ID in TokBox API?

Tags: tokbox

How to calculate Session Duration or Call Duration in TokBox API?

We need to display Session/Call duration for each Session-Id, we created from Backend. In our case, only 2 people can connect to a session as we are sharing session-id & token with two users only. Now On the Admin Panel, we need the Actual Call time between these two users.

Is there any API which provides these statics?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API to calculate the exact call duration.
You can check your invoices on the dashboard under the billing section.

Another way is, you can log the timestamps on event listeners. Like when the first-person joins the session, connectionCreated event gets fired, in that you can log your time stamp and send it to your server. Similarly, when someone leaves the session, you get connectionDestroyed event. Refer to [this page](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/ConnectionEvent.html) for all events related to the session.

You can also refer to our Session Monitoring API - https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/session-monitoring/ which lets you receive real-time session callback events on your server endpoint thereby monitoring the user's session activity.

By using the events mentioned above you can calculate the session duration.

Thanks!